# Is there any other way to fetch records from servicenow using soap api?

Tags: powershell, soap

I am a PowerShell beginner and trying to fetch records from ServiceNow but I am not getting any records and error.

```
$username = 'username'
$password = 'Mypassword'
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,`
(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -For
 
$sn =New-WebServiceProxy -Uri 'https://<My instance>.service-now.com/incident.do?WSDL' -Credential $cred
$type = $sn.GetType().Namespace

$getRecords = new-object ($type + '.getRecords')
$getRecords.state=3
$sn.getRecords($getRecords)
```

Comment: I looked and ServiceNow appears to have a [RESTAPI](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-application-development/page/build/applications/concept/api-rest.html) With this you can use [invoke-restmethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1) to get the information you are looking for. I hope this helps some.

Comment: I would also recommend using the REST API and possibly utilize one of the ServiceNow powershell modules, such as this one: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ServiceNow/1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the web-services reference from SNOW?
Here it is: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-application-development/page/integrate/web-services/reference/r_AvailableWebServices.html

SNOW supports SOAP and REST.  If you haven't a explicit reason to use SOAP, I advise you to switch to REST, it is much more easy to use.

If you have to use SOAP, possibly this is interesting for you:
https://gist.github.com/JohnLBevan/5f8b544733f52eeca8cfad4b457bf604